# MarshalAs for Properties in a struct

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to add getters and setters to this struct, so I can use it as a listView items source. The problem is, this causes MarshalAs to be invalid thus not allowing compilation. What would the best option be to fix this?

> Attribute 'MarshalAs' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field, parameter, return' declarations.**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct FileExplorerData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 251)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public FILETIME lastwrite { get; set; }
        public bool type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
    };
```

Comment: Simple - `MarshalAs` must not be available for `property`

Comment: Yes @T.S., that is precisely the issue. Do you have a solution you can recommend?

Comment: `[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field | System.AttributeTargets.Parameter | System.AttributeTargets.ReturnValue, Inherited=false)]` -- this is your solution

Comment: But why do you need this for datasource? Is this winforms or WPF?

Comment: @T.S. I have a list of these structs that I set as a data source for a WPF listview.

Comment: @T.S. Can you post an answer with that if that is a correct solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the underlying field as the target of the attribute

```cs
[field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 251)]
public string name { get; set; }
```

This is valid from C# 7.3+. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties#attaching-attributes-to-auto-implemented-properties).